# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RelativeLayout.getChildCount()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am learning android development.
I want to make the sliding puzzle game.
I just seent the Youtube Tutorial, and i am sure this code is same as the tutorial.
But this code got error then cause the app force close.

This problem make the app force closed. Please help.

Here is the code

**MainActiviy.java**

```
package com.maulana.slidingpuzzle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button buttonStart;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonStart = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**GameActivity.java**

```
package com.maulana.slidingpuzzle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  int emptyX=3;
    private  int emptyY=3;
    private RelativeLayout group;
    private Button[][] buttons;
    private int[] tiles;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        loadNumbers();
        loadViews();
        generateNumbers();
        loadDataToViews();
    }
    private void loadViews(){
        group = findViewById(R.id.groupPuzzle);
        buttons = new Button[3][4];

        for (int i =0; i<group.getChildCount();i++){
            buttons[i/3][i%4] = (Button) group.getChildAt(i);
        }
        return;
    }

    private void loadDataToViews(){
        emptyX=3;
        emptyY=3;
        for(int i = 0; i <group.getChildCount()-1; i++){
            buttons[i/3][i%4].setText(String.valueOf(tiles[i]));
            buttons[i/3][i%4].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
        }
        buttons[emptyX][emptyY].setText("");
        buttons[emptyX][emptyY].setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorFreeButton));
    }
    private void loadNumbers(){
        tiles = new int[16];
        for(int i =0; i< group.getChildCount() -1;i++){
            tiles[i]=i+1;
        }
    }

    private  void generateNumbers(){
        int n = 11;
        Random random = new Random();
        while (n>1){
            int randomNum = random.nextInt(n--);
            int temp = tiles[randomNum];
            tiles[randomNum]=tiles[n];
            tiles[n] =temp;
        }
        if(!isSolvable())
            generateNumbers();
    }
    private boolean isSolvable(){
        int countInversion = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<11;i++){
            for (int j =0; j<i; j++){
                if(tiles[j]>tiles[i])
                    countInversion++;
            }
        }
        return countInversion%2 == 0;
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view){
        Button button = (Button) view;
        int x = button.getTag().toString().charAt(0)-'0';
        int y = button.getTag().toString().charAt(1)-'0';

        if ((Math.abs(emptyX-x)==1&&emptyY==y) || (Math.abs(emptyY-y)==1 && emptyX ==x)){
            buttons[emptyX][emptyY].setText((button.getText().toString()));
            buttons[emptyX][emptyY].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
            button.setText("");
            button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorFreeButton));
            emptyY = y;
            emptyX = x;
            checkWin();
        }
    }

    private  void checkWin(){
        boolean isWin = false;
        if(emptyX==3 && emptyY==3){
            for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount()-1; i++){
                if(buttons[i/3][i%4].getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(i+1))){
                    isWin = true;
                }
                else {
                    isWin = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (isWin){
            Toast.makeText(this, "MENANG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (int i = 0; i <group.getChildCount();i++){
                buttons[i/3][i%4].setClickable(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_game.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/groupPuzzle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:tag="01"
            android:text="A"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonA"
            android:tag="02"
            android:text="B"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonB"
            android:tag="03"
            android:text="C"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonA"
            android:tag="04"
            android:text="D"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonE"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonD"
            android:tag="05"
            android:text="E"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonF"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonE"
            android:tag="06"
            android:text="F"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonG"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonD"
            android:tag="07"
            android:text="G"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonH"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonE"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonG"
            android:tag="08"
            android:text="H"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonI"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonF"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonH"
            android:tag="09"
            android:text="I"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonJ"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonG"
            android:tag="10"
            android:text="J"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonK"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonH"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonJ"
            android:tag="11"
            android:text="K"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/freeButton"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonI"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonK"
            android:tag="12"
            android:text="-"
            android:background="@color/colorFreeButton"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Start Puzzle Game"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

So i want when the button was clicked, the app open the GameActivity.

Comment: `#findViewById` returned `null`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).